# userform vlookup in textbox

Tags: outlook, vlookup, userform

I am really new to VBA, was trying to play around with really basic things, userform and vlookup. Couldn't figure out vlookup error after many hours. Appreciate any input!

```
Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub cmdSend_Click()

' emailcommand Macro

'
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMail As MailItem
Set oApp = New Outlook.Application
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

With oMail
    .To = emailaddress.Value
    .Subject = Subjectbox.Value
    .Body = "Hi, " & Fundname.Value & " is ready"
    .Display
    Application.SendKeys "%s"
End With

End Sub


Private Sub Fundnumber_Change()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Matrix")

With Me
    .Fundname.Text = Application.VLookup(.Fundnumber.Text, ws.Range("A2:D141"), 4, False)
End With

End Sub
```